# Should I wrap React.cloneElement into useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I read the official React [doc for cloneElement](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/cloneElement#overriding-props-of-an-element). I also checked how exactly the MUI ToggleButton component is implemented and [overrides the children](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/master/packages/mui-material/src/ToggleButtonGroup/ToggleButtonGroup.js#L158). In both cases there is no mention on that we should wrap it into useEffect to prevent each time recalculation.

Don't we need to wrap cloneElement, especially when we do Children.map, into useEffect to prevent this potentially heavy operation each time the component rerenders?

I created a [code example](https://codesandbox.io/s/broken-brook-dx2cl9?file=/List.js) where it clearly seen it is always recalled.

Comment: "prevent this potentially heavy operation" how heavy is this operation? Not potentially, in reality.

Comment: It doesn't matter. The fact of creation of the new objects from a long list of items is not a good thing, on my opinion, especially when there is no reason of doing this (i.e. actual array is not changed or the dependency props of the component)

Comment: Could I interrest you in a talk. [React Rally 2019 - React Hook Pitfalls](https://youtu.be/VIRcX2X7EUk?t=1165) The segment I've linked is titled "Overtihinking Performance" and among other things the speaker addresses memo, useCallback, etc. and their performance impact *(nothing comes for free)*

Comment: @Thomas, in this video actually said not to do a really simple stuff in such hook methods.  In my particular case there might be hundreds of elements and the value can change quite often. And each time being triggered for remapping them via clone element seems could really slow the app. I believe if I wrapped this .map stuff into useEffect/useMemo I could prevent this from happening. Don't you agree?